# Find an $\alpha$ such that $T_i\alpha \neq T_j\alpha$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $T_1, \cdots , T_m$ are linear operators from linear space $V$ to $V$, such that $T_i \neq T_j$ for all $i \neq j$.

Prove that there exists an $\alpha \in V$ such that $T_i\alpha \neq T_j\alpha$ for all $i \neq j$.

PS: Can this be done without using induction?

Comment: Over which field is $V$? I don't think it is true over every field.

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting each one of the transformations from all the others, we get a finite collection of transformations, call them $S_1,\ldots,S_k$, and by assumption $S_i\neq0$ for every $i$. It is enough now to prove that there is $\alpha\in V$ such that $S_i(\alpha)\neq0$ for all $i$. Let $K_i\subset V$ denote the kernel of $S_i$, so for every $i$ $\dim K_i\leq n-1$, where $n$ is the dimension of $V$.

Assuming that the field of scalars $\mathbb{F}$ is *infinite*, a finite union of proper subspaces can not be the whole space, thus there is $\alpha\in V\setminus\bigcup K_i$, and the proof is complete.